# Python 3 Multiprocessing - how to execute a single task

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, web-crawler

Much appreciated in advance !

**Task Description:** 
I would like to use Python to collect the free https proxy server information and test.  The codes takes a few minutes to run (about 100 proxy servers to test), I understand multiprocessing can remarkably increasing the executing speed, however, I tried a few days but no luck ... seems that all sub-processes are doing the duplicate tasks, rather than doing together.

Need assistance here ...

**Codes:**

```
import requests
import re
import telnetlib
import multiprocessing

def run(info1, info2):
    try:
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(info1, port= info2, timeout= 2)
    except:
        print('not working !')
    else:
        proxy_server = 'http://' + info1 + ':' + info2
        print(proxy_server)

if __name__=='__main__':
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36'}
    html = requests.get('https://www.sslproxies.org', headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
    pattern = re.compile('<td>(\d.*?)</td><td>(\d+)</td>', re.S)
    items = re.findall(pattern, html.text)
    for item in items:
        for i in range(5):
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run(item[0], item[1]), args=('msc%s' % i,))
            p.start()
```

Comment: `for item in items:` looks problematic. You're spawning 5 processes for each individual item

Comment: I can't test your code so I can only give suggestions. I think you'll be better using an asynchronous library for making requests like [requests-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures). `multiprocessing` is pretty heavy, but in order to make it work like you're trying, you need to reverse your approach. Instead of launching in a `for` loop, you should chunk a list of URLs and send each chunk to an individual process

Comment: Hi roganjosh,  thanks for your advice, I will do some research and use requests-futures :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The "for i in range(5)" was spawning the same process 5 times, creating repetition. This can be achieved simply by removing it and creating the process in a simpler way.

```
    for item in items:
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run, args=(item[0], item[1],))
            p.start()
```

Comment: This is horribly inefficient. Why spawn a single process for each request?

Comment: Because the objective of multiprocessing is run each request independent in parallel. And works best like this.

Comment: For some amount of items, sure, but there's probably a limit to amount of processes vs. items to process where the costs of processes start to show. In other words the worker pools probably exist for a reason.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have tried this one and it works ! It takes 12-14 s to complete 100 entries, much better than before.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is basically IO bound (you are requesting information from many distant servers), hence you need to "concurrently" request all the servers and wait for their replies. This is the typical use case where you should use concurrency capabilities of languages such as Python. Somehow, multiprocessing is one way to achieve concurrency (strictly speaking such an assertion is not correct) but what happen if you need to request thousands of servers? Creating thousands of process is not the good way to go.

I recommand this article: https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html

It will help you to achieve what you're trying to do in a very efficient way.

Comment: The article is good, but I think this answer would be better if it featured a snipped of the portion that would be needed to solve OP's problem.

Comment: Hi ohe, thanks for the advice and article, async is new to me but I am leaning :)